# Iterating over group within a group in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Rookie question. I have a field group set up in ACF to hold a grid of 11 blocks. This is structured as 
a group containing 11 sub-groups, each of which holds four elements; an image, a link and two blocks of text.

I've written code long-hand to populate the content onto the page, and it works, but it's not exactly efficient. I'm now trying to refactor the code to eliminate repetition, but I think my syntax is letting me down.

Here's the working code:

```
<?php
if (have_rows('feature_grid')) {
  while ( have_rows( 'feature_grid' ) ) {
    the_row();

      while (have_rows('grid_box_1')){
        the_row();
        $header1 = get_sub_field('header');
        $subheader1 = get_sub_field('sub-header');
        $image1 = get_sub_field('image');
        $link1 = get_sub_field('link');
      }

      while (have_rows('grid_box_2')){
        the_row();
        $header2 = get_sub_field('header');
        $subheader2 = get_sub_field('sub-header');
        $image2 = get_sub_field('image');
        $link2 = get_sub_field('link');
      }

      // ...etc...

   }
}
?>
```

Here's my attempt at refactoring.

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=11; $i++){
  if (have_rows('feature_grid')) {
    while (have_rows('feature_grid')) {
      the_row();
      while (have_rows('grid_box_'.$i)) {
        the_row();
        $header[$i] = get_sub_field('header');
        $subheader[$i] = get_sub_field('sub-header');
        $image[$i] = get_sub_field('image');
        $link[$i] = get_sub_field('link'); 
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

In practice, this doesn't populate the content. Where am I going wrong? I'm pretty sure the issue is my syntax around appending i to the variables, but so far I've not managed to work out what the *correct* syntax should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the variables which are going to be reused in each loop.

```
$header = 'header';
$subheader = 'subheader';
$image = 'image';
$link = 'link';
```

Then you can change your code as below:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=11; $i++){
  if (have_rows('feature_grid')) {
    while (have_rows('feature_grid')) {
      the_row();
      while (have_rows('grid_box_'.$i)) {
        the_row();
        ${$header.$i}  = get_sub_field('header');
        ${$subheader.$i}  = get_sub_field('sub-header');
        ${$image.$i}  = get_sub_field('image');
        ${$link.$i}  = get_sub_field('link'); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```